# Tasks of a Yarn Process in Hadoop

Tags: bigdata, apache-hadoop

I am new to big data and [Apache Hadoop YARN](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html). This picture show how Yarn runs applications:

[image]

A client requests a Yarn Application. So, in a certain datanode a Container is created and the process is made to run.

This means that every task of a Yarn Application are run is the same datanode?